# Getting authentication token set through JQuery in JMeter

Tags: jquery, jmeter, csrf, jmeter-plugins

My application under test has sequence of network requests that use [CSRF Token](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) technique for authentication.

I am able to get `_csrf` token which is set through:

```
"meta id="csrf" content=*_VALUE_*"
```

One of the sequential requests have JQuery snippet that sets `"X-CSRF-Token"` for next requests to be made:

```
ajaxPrefilter = function(jQuery) {

      jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
         var csrfToken = jQuery('#csrf').attr('content');
         jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token, csrfToken);

      });
};
```

The same `X-CSRF-Token` is used in next sequential request's Request Header [i.e. set through JQuery in previous requests] which leads to `Forbidden error` in all the network requests having Request parameter `X-CSRF-Token` in the Request Header.

How can I overcome "Forbidden" error caused due to the Token?
Is there anything through which I can get the JQuery parameter[Token] value set in previous requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is classic correlation example. Looking into the code I see that JQuery extracts `content` attribute from something having id `csrf` and puts it into `X-CSRF-Token` header.

To replicate this behavior:

- Add [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) as a child of the first request
- Configure it as follows:

  - Reference name: anything meaningful, i.e. `token`
  - CSS/JQuery Expression: `#csrf`
  - Attribute: `content`

The steps above will extract CSRF token from page source and store it to `token` JMeter Variable. You can now add a relevant header using [HTTP Header Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager)

- Add a HTTP Header Manager element as a child of the request which is failing with "Forbidden"
- Configure it as follows:

  - Name: `X-CSRF-Token`
  - Value: `${token}`

Repeat above steps for all CSRF-protected requests and get pie.

Hope this helps.